# Android - Conforming with the new ADT's ActionBarActivity structure

Tags: android, fragment

I'm new to `Android` programming, after reading some guides, the convention is that you typically make a separate class for `Activities` and `Fragments`. However, the new ADT creates a MainActivity that extends `ActionBarActivity`. In contrast to replacing `ActionBarActivity` with `Activity` and remove other `Fragment`-related code, I want to work with the default structure ADT provided.

The main concern is that the `Fragment` (PlaceholderFragment) is a nested static class. Is this even good practice? I think creating a separate `Fragment` class would be much more modular and simple. One benefit is that I can replace the `Fragment` with a different one in the main view.

Again, I'm fairly new so if there are indeed benefits to having a nested static class for the main `Fragment` instead of in a new file, please let me know. Or should I create a separate `Fragment` class?

Comment: Just depends on your coding styles really. I break mine out into files and packages unless they are dialogs that aren't shared, then they are static. ActionBarActivity extends activity.

Answer (score 0):

why you wanna use old ADT structure version?

Accustom yourself to new ADT and learn `fragments` and Cool `ActionBar`,
first by extends `ActionBarActivity` you just support `ActionBar` in old version and evry thing same here such as normal `Activity`

2- as you can see new ADT added new support library called `support-v7` so you can use `ActionBar` in old version

[image]

3- the static `Fragmen` called "`PlaceholderFragment`" inside `MainActivity` Is this good practice? well `google` developers added this thing to me and i trust `google`.

i hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to use the old ADT structure. But what I don't get is why use nested static class for mainactivity's fragment? For example, what if you realize that you want a different fragment in mainactivity. The nested static fragment would then be out of sync since a different activity may use it.

Comment: well this added from `googel` to general developers if you wanna do customize to yourself just customize your logic as you want, if you wanna use different `Fragment`  in `MainActivity` you already built it then simply remove the static `Fragment` and add yours by `FargmentManger` or From `Xml` file it's depend in your logic.

Comment: if this is good answer to you it will be nice if you give me Voteup or best answer coz there is no one answered else me.